# What would be the most optimised way to access values in a nested array whilst respecting pep8?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pep8

I have been using nested arrays parsed from a json.
This ends up giving a gigantic line each time I try to access values in the data.
let's say I have a nested array in the var data, when I try to reach the deeper values, I still have to respect the 80 characters limit. All I want to do is read or modify the value.

```
self.data["name1"]["name2"][varWithNumber][varWithNumber2][varWithNumber3]
```

Now, I thought about two possible solutions I could use:

1- split it using temporary vars and then reasign it to the data once I am done ex:

```
tempData=self.data["name1"]["name2"][varWithNumber]
tempData[varWithNumber2][varWithNumber3]+=1
self.data["name1"]["name2"][varWithNumber]=tempData
```

I guess this solution would use quite a bit of ressources from all the memory copied around.

2- use the exec function implemented in python and split the string on multiple lines:

```
exec ('self.data'+
      '["name1"]'+
      '["name2"]'+
      '[varWithNumber]'+
      '[varWithNumber2]'+
      '[varWithNumber3]+=1')
```

I have no idea how optimised is the exec function. What would be the most pythonic/optimised way to do this? Is there any other/better way to reach the goal whilst respecting the pep8?

Comment: The way I see it, is if you run something like flake8 or similar, and things pass, you're good. Beyond that, it's all going to be matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Bit long for a comment) You don't need exec to do that... you can use the line continuation operator:

```
self.data["name1"]\
         ["name2"]\
         [varWithNumber]\
         [varWithNumber2]\ 
         [varWithNumber3]
```

Demo:

```
In [635]: x = [[[[1, 2, 3]]]]

In [636]: x[0]\
     ...:  [0]\
     ...:  [0]\
     ...:  [0]
Out[636]: 1
```

This seems like the easiest and cleanest way to do it.

Don't use `exec` unless you have to. Actually, don't use it, ever.

---

In some cases, keeping a reference to a sub dict works if you are to frequently visit that part of your data structure again and again. It is a matter of deciding what is the best solution to apply given the situation and circumstances.

Comment: Nice! I knew this existed in batch and cmd, but for some reason I thought this didn't exist in python. I am pretty sure this is the best and easiest way to do it. Thank you :)!

Comment: @AlexandreMercierAubin For the most part, this improves readability without having to resort to shady tactics like `exec`. But like idjaw said, it's a matter of opinion and what best fits the situation. Do what you feel is best as long as you confirm to PEP.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with your first option, and it's not as memory intensive as you might think. Most things in python are references to places in memory, so let's say we have this json blob (dict in python):

```
test = {
    "name1": {
        "name2": {
            "foo": {
                "count": 1,
                "color": "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you wanted to change both parts of that nested "foo" key, you could first make a reference to it with:

```
foo_ref = test['name1']['name2']['foo']
```

Then it's very simple to just

```
foo_ref['count'] += 1
foo_ref['color'] = 'green'
```